# Creating a MaterialButton programatically, theme error

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, material-components-android

Trying to create a MaterialButton programatically:

```
private val button = MaterialButton(context, null, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Button)
```

But I am getting the following error when it tries to render:

`Failed to find '@attr/textAppearanceButton' in current theme.`

I tried to pass in a context that uses my App theme, which is extending from.

`"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Tried multiple styles while initialising, no change in the result.

No Luck, any ideas what might i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update your theme to inherit from one of the MaterialComponents themes, like:

`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

See https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started

Note that you should be able to just initialize via the single-argument constructor:

```
private val button = MaterialButton(context)
```

Provided that the `Context` you're using is themed (either the `Activity`, or the `Application` if you've set the theme on the `<application>` tag).

Comment: Thank you Kevin, Unfortunately changing the app theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` does not work, and yes i also tried initialising it with just the context too, although i did try providing custom styles just to fix the issue.

Comment: Just to verify there's not some theming issue, try doing something like:

`private val button = MaterialButton(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_NoActionBar))`

Comment: Notably, the third argument in the constructor should not be a style reference -- it should be an attribute reference, e.g. `R.attr.myCustomMaterialButtonStyle`, but generally you would have no need for that.

Comment: Kevin thank you! `private val button = MaterialButton(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_NoActionBar))` works!